# How to save login data in Excel worksheet using html ?

Tags: html, excel, vbscript

What i need

- I need to save login data in excel sheet while user click submit button in html.

Still what i done

- using vb-script i have done this.

Errors

- Sub Sample() undefined script errors.
- data not saving
- dialog box not responding

[this is my excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPw4t.jpg)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script language="vbscript" type="text/vbscript">
Sub Sample()
debugger;
Dim iRow
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("E:\excel\work.xlsx")
'Document.GetElementsByName("fname")(0).Value="C#"
'Document.GetElementsByName("lname")(0).Value="Corner"
'Document.GetElementsByName("Add1")(0).Value="Tamilnadu"
'Document.GetElementsByName("Add2")(0).Value="Coimbatore"
objExcel.Application.Visible = True
objWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = True
set XlSheet =objWorkbook.Sheets(1)
XlSheet.Activate
iRow = 1
With objExcel
Do While .Cells(iRow, 1).value <> ""
.Cells(iRow, 1).activate
iRow = iRow + 1
Loop
.Cells(iRow, 1).value=Document.GetElementsByName("fname")(0).Value
.Cells(iRow, 2).value=Document.GetElementsByName("lname")(0).Value
.Cells(iRow, 3).value=Document.GetElementsByName("Add1")(0).Value
.Cells(iRow, 4).value=Document.GetElementsByName("Add2")(0).Value
MsgBox "Data Added Sucessfully",vbinformation
Document.GetElementsByName("fname")(0).Value=""
Document.GetElementsByName("lname")(0).Value=""
Document.GetElementsByName("Add1")(0).Value=""
Document.GetElementsByName("Add2")(0).Value=""
End With
objWorkbook.save
objWorkbook.close
Set objWorkbook = Nothing
Set objExcel = Nothing
End Sub
</script>
<style type="text/css">
fieldset {
border: #00cc00 2px solid;
padding: 10px;
color:green;
</style>
<body
<form>
<fieldset>
<legend>Csharpcorner</legend>
<center>
<img src="C:\Users\Karthikeyan.K\Desktop\Add-Male-User.png" alt="Mountain View"><br>
First name:<br> 
<input type="text" name="fname" Value=""><br>
Last name:<br>
<input type="text" name="lname" Value=""><br>
Address1:<br>
<input type="text" name="Add1" Value=""><br>
Address2 :<br>
<input type="text" name="Add2" Value=""><br>
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="Sample()" value="Submit" /><br>
</center>
</fieldset>
<form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you use JavaScript instead of vb-script?

Comment: yes , but didn't get proper result

Comment: ok, please share your code